# I get into a endless loop in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I want to find out a intersect between two linked list which already sorted,but I get into a endless loop ,I know I set wrong condition after while but I don't know how to fix that. pls help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}list;

list *intersect(list *L1, list *L2) {
    list *Result;
    list *L1Pos, *L2Pos, *ResultPos;

    L1Pos = L1;
    L2Pos = L2;
    Result = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
    ResultPos = Result;
    while(L1Pos != NULL && L2Pos != NULL) {         //endless loop
        if(L1Pos->data < L2Pos->data) {
            L1Pos = L1Pos->next;
        } else if(L1Pos->data > L2Pos->data) {
            L2Pos = L2Pos->next;
        } else {
            ResultPos->data = L1Pos->data;
            L1 = L1Pos->next;
            L2 = L2Pos->next;
            ResultPos->next = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
            ResultPos = ResultPos->next;
        }
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line to see what happens.

Comment: what are the values in 2 linked lists l1 and l2 which causes this loop. post that.

Comment: If you think any answer answered your question please accept it (The green checkmark next to the answer). This will indicate to the community that you have found the solution, and will give some reputation to you and the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

When you find the intersection, you don't change the values of `L1Pos` and `L2Pos`, so the loop keeps choosing the final else statement forever.

If you want to end the loop, use break or set one of the mentioned variables to NULL.

Otherwise you can set both nodes to the next node and let the loop continue until the end of the list:

```
L1Pos = L1Pos->next;
L2Pos = L2Pos->next;
```

Also your allocation of `Result` is questionable, since the node is allocated before it is even known if the loop found any result, so the return node could contain uninitialized values, and the final node in the list `Result` will always contain uninitialized values. Instead of allocating in advance, allocate when you do find the node, and set the next pointer of than new node to NULL so the list is terminated. In the case nothing is found, the function will return `Result`, which will be NULL (as it will be initialized to NULL before the loop).

Answer (score 1):

if  `L1Pos->data == L2Pos->data` your loop won't terminate. You mixed `L1` with `L1Pos` and `L2` with `L2Pos`. Apart from this only allocate your result node if it is needed, otherwise you will always have a node with uninitialized data:

```
list *intersect(list *L1, list *L2) {
    list *L1Pos = L1;
    list *L2Pos = L2;
    list *Result = NULL;
    list **ResultPos = &Result; // ResultPos refers to 'Result'
    while(L1Pos != NULL && L2Pos != NULL) {
        if(L1Pos->data < L2Pos->data) {
            L1Pos = L1Pos->next;
        } else if(L1Pos->data > L2Pos->data) {
            L2Pos = L2Pos->next;
        } else {

            *ResultPos = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
            (*ResultPos)->data = L1Pos->data;
            (*ResultPos)->next = NULL;         // successor of last result is NULL
            ResultPos = &((*ResultPos)->next); // ResultPos now refers to 'next' 

            L1Pos = L1Pos->next;
         // ^^^^^
            L2Pos = L2Pos->next;
         // ^^^^^
        }
    }
    return Result;
}
```